# iptables, allow connections from subnet A to Internet over gateway B

Tags: iptables

For a university assignment, I need to configure an `iptables` firewall.

I want to allow connections from subnet `136.155.96.37/25` to the internet. The 
internet is available under the gateway `152.183.38.163`.

For now I have this:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 136.155.96.37/25 -d 152.183.38.163 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

This configuration has to be done in your GW.

Setup the `FORWARD` chain.

```
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Where

> eth1 = internal interfece
>
> eth0 = external interface

This will set the inbound & outbound interfaces where the forwarding's gonna be done.

Check that the forward option is `1`

```
$ sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf
> net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Set this new configuration

```
$ sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
 net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Setup the `POSTROUTING` chain

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 136.155.96.37/25 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 152.183.38.163
$ sudo iptables-t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

For more info check out the [This documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Security_Guide/index.html#sect-Security_Guide-Firewalls-FORWARD_and_NAT_Rules)

Give a try

Comment: What's a GW...?

Comment: @mikeserv GateWay